# Storing Options in a Shortcode

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I am creating a Wordpress plugin.  I want to create 1 single shortcode that changes output based on the settings changed by the user on the admin settings page.

So for starters, I have something like this below:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode');
  function my_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts (
  array (
  'display' => get_option('setting_1'),
  'toolbar' => get_option('setting_2'),
  'branding' => get_option('setting_3')
  ), $atts);
     }
```

What do I need to do next in order to store these settings into a single shortcode that keeps it's name despite the settings changing?

Comment: hat do you mean store options? Is this a question about shortcodes?  Or how to create an admin page with options?

Comment: I need to take the settings chosen by the user on the setting page (already created) and then store them into a shortcode that displays HTML based on those chosen settings.  I know this is a general question, so I apologize for not being more specific, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to alter display based on admin options, you don't need to deal at all with the `shortcode_atts` ar the `$attributes` that are passed into your callback.  The attributes passed in (and set by `shortcode_atts`) are meant to alter the way a shortcode works based on how an end-user uses it.

Take this: `[wpse75238 arg1="asdf" arg2="asdf"]`

```
<?php
add_shortcode('wpse75238', 'wpse75238_shortcode_cb');
function wpse75238_shortcode_cb($atts)
{
    return var_export($atts);
}
```

Something like `array ( 'arg1' => 'asdf', 'arg2' => 'asdf' )` will come out.

[`shortcode_atts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) just sets defaults for you (and removes "unauthorized" keys) in a similar way to [`wp_parse_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args).

If you just want to change stuff based on an admin page option, you don't need to respect the user input.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('wpse75238', 'wpse75238_shortcode_cb');
function wpse75238_shortcode_cb()
{
    if('some_value' = get_option('wpse75238_opts'))
    {
        // do stuff because some_value was set.
    }
}
```

Calling the shortcode with arguments will not change a thing for the above shortcode.

Comment: thanks chris - I scrapped my function completely and applied your logic to another already-existing function and it worked. Thanks